# Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined at null:1

Tags: android, android-webview, getelementbyid

I am trying to get the contents of `hiddenDivHL` which is present in the part of the following **HTML page :**

```
 <div id='hiddenDivHL' style='display:none'>http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123663[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_215842267.jpg[InnerSep]ಹಾಕಿ ಸರಣಿ ಗೆದ್ದ ಭಾರತ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123661[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_215521230.jpg[InnerSep]ಟಾಪ್‌-10: ಜಹೀರ್‌, ಸಚಿನ್‌ ಮಾತ್ರ...[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123659[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_214720800.jpg[InnerSep]ಫೆಡರರ್‌, ನಡಾಲ್‌ ನಾಲ್ಕನೇ ಸುತ್ತಿಗೆ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123658[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_212550060.jpg[InnerSep]ಆರ್‌ಸಿಬಿಯಲ್ಲೇ ಉಳಿದ ಕ್ರಿಸ್‌ ಗೇಲ್‌[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123657[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_212421517.jpg[InnerSep]ಎಐಟಿಎ ಧೋರಣೆಗೆ ಭೂಪತಿ ಕಿಡಿ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123655[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_211511413.jpg[InnerSep]ಐಪಿಎಲ್‌ ಹರಾಜಿನಲ್ಲಿ 183 ಆಟಗಾರರು[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123622[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_201031107.jpg[InnerSep]ಸಾಕ್ಷಿ ಕುತ್ತಿಗೆಯಲ್ಲಿ ಮಹಿ ಟ್ಯಾಟೂ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123579[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_171346020.jpg[InnerSep]ಒತ್ತಡವೇನಿಲ್ಲ: ಸಾಹಾ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123578[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_171314597.jpg[InnerSep]ಏಶ್ಯನ್‌ ಶೂಟಿಂಗ್‌: ವಿಜಯ್‌ಗೆ ಚಿನ್ನ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123569[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_163014790.jpg[InnerSep]ಬಾಂಗ್ಲಾ ಲೀಗ್‌ಗಿಂತ ತವರಿನ ಸೇವೆ ಮುಖ್ಯ...[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123656[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_212321253.jpg[InnerSep]ರಣಜಿ ಫೈನಲ್‌: ರಾಜಸ್ಥಾನ ಬಿಗಿ ಹಿಡಿತ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123568[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_162923840.jpg[InnerSep]ಅಡಿಲೇಡ್‌ನ‌ಲ್ಲಿ ಕಾದಿದೆ ಎಕ್ಸ್‌ಟ್ರಾ ಬೌನ್ಸ್‌, ಮೋರ್‌ ಗ್ರಾಸ್‌...[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123631[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg120_Jan_2012_202426003.jpg[InnerSep]ಹೆಜಮಾಡಿ: ಜಿಲ್ಲಾಮಟ್ಟದ ಕ್ರಿಕೆಟ್‌ ಪಂದ್ಯಾಟ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123629[InnerSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/images/udayavani.png[InnerSep]ಇಂದು ಉಡುಪಿಯಲ್ಲಿ ಹೊನಲು ಬೆಳಕಿನ ವಾಲಿಬಾಲ್‌[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123542[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_233254747.jpg[InnerSep]ಟೀಮ್‌ ಇಂಡಿಯಾ ಶಾಪಿಂಗ್‌; ಲಕ್ಷ್ಮಣ್‌ ಪ್ರ್ಯಾಕ್ಟೀಸ್‌[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123541[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_233157827.jpg[InnerSep]ಪಾಕಿಸ್ಥಾನ ಜಯಭೇರಿ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123540[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_232902477.jpg[InnerSep]ಸಾನಿಯಾ-ವೆಸ್ನಿನಾ ದ್ವಿತೀಯ ಸುತ್ತು ಪ್ರವೇಶ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123539[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_232547687.jpg[InnerSep]ಹಾಕಿ: ಭಾರತದ ಕ್ಲೀನ್‌ಸ್ವೀಪ್‌ ಸಾಧನೆ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123538[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_232335163.jpg[InnerSep]ಬಾಂಗ್ಲಾ ಪ್ರೀಮಿಯರ ಲೀಗ್‌: ಅಫ್ರಿದಿಗೆ ಬಂಪರ್‌[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123537[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_231809443.jpg[InnerSep]ಮೂರಕ್ಕೆ ನೆಗೆದ ಜೊಕೋವಿಕ್‌, ಸೆರೆನಾ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123536[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_231141100.jpg[InnerSep]ಆಸ್ಟ್ರೇಲಿಯನ್‌ ಓಪನ್‌ನಲ್ಲಿ ಟ್ಯಾಟೂಗಳ ಲೋಕ...[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123531[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_230000680.jpg[InnerSep]ವೆಸ್ಟ್‌ಇಂಡೀಸ್‌ ವಿರುದ್ಧ ನಾನು ಬಹಳಷ್ಟು ಆಟವನ್ನು ಆನಂದಿಸಿದ್ದೇನೆ[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123529[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_225728670.jpg[InnerSep]ಹಾಕಿ: ಭಾರತಕ್ಕೆ ಸೋಲು[OuterSep]http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=884&newsid=123525[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg119_Jan_2012_225325587.jpg[InnerSep]ರಾಜಸ್ಥಾನ ನೋಲಾಸ್‌ ಬ್ಯಾಟಿಂಗ್‌</div>
```

using the below code:

```
 public class WesActivity extends Activity {
  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

     mWebView.loadUrl("http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details_android.php?home=1&catid=894&newsid=28100");
     mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
     mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:getElementById('hiddenDivHL')");
 
     }

final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        Log.d("LogTag", message);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        result.confirm();
        return true;
       }
    }
  }
```

and I am getting error as:

> 01-21 12:22:24.660: E/Web Console(5527): Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined at null:1
>
> 01-21 12:22:27.840: E/Web Console(5527): Uncaught ReferenceError: callTimer is not defined at http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details_android.php?home=1&catid=894&newsid=28100:434

I have got questions,

- Since I have no idea whatsoever on to loading a HTML page, I want to know,is this the right way to extract the contents of HTML page?
- I have no idea about the error I am getting

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be `javascript:alert(document.getElementById('theid').innerHTML())` or something alike and it must be executed when the page is loaded fully.

Like this: [In Android Webview, am I able to modify a webpage's DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219074/in-android-webview-am-i-able-to-modify-a-webpages-dom)

Of course enable JavaScript in the WebView.

Comment: I have enabled the JavaScript and used `javascript:alert(document.getElementById('theid').innerHTML())` as told.But still the same problem persists and one more thing I am unable to load the link provided by you @Deucalion

Comment: Yes, url was messed. Just Google last URL segment or for 2219074 stackoverflow. Change 'theId' to the HTML element id. Show the code after modifications.