# How can I prevent an Android WebView from manipulating a web page?

Tags: android, security, android-webview

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219074/in-android-webview-am-i-able-to-modify-a-webpages-dom) it is possible to:
1. Create an Android WebView with setJavaScriptEnabled=true
2. Load a URL
3. Override onPageFinished and change the Web page displayed to the user

Now, is it possible for the Web page owner to implement anything server-side which prevents this from happening? The risk is that a malicious app could spoof the user by amending the Web page for nefarious means...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really possible to prevent the web response being modified. You can only think of making it difficult for the spoofer to edit it.