# android webview zoom at specific area

Tags: java, android, webview

Is it possible to display a area from a website in webview. without display the whole page.

i have this website http://roosters.gepro-osi.nl/roosters/rooster.php?leerling=116277&type=Leerlingrooster&afdeling=12-13_OVERIG&school=905 .

and i only want to display the table in webview. any help?

Answer (score 0):

Zooming to the right area is a little dirty I think. When the page changes the layout, you'll need to update your app. Also, it might look nice on your screen but ugly on others.

My idea would be to use JavaScript in the context of the loaded page, to manipulate the DOM so only the table is shown (which is a simple `<table>`). See this question: [In Android Webview, am I able to modify a webpage's DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2219074/717341)

If you can influence the HTML on the page, help yourself and give the desired table an id.