# Android WebView: display only some part of website

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I wanted to know if it was possible to display only certain parts of a website in a WebView. For example I have this website with the following html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="1">ID 1</id>
<div id="2">ID 2</id>
<div id="3">ID 3</id>
</body>
</html>
```

it is possible to display in WebView only, for example, the contents of the div with id="3"?
My code is WebWiew:

```
WebViewClient WebClient = new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
        }
    };


    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(WebClient);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
}
```

Comment: Please do not locate your code 'off-site', especially with such small code snippets! Instead update your question and use code blocks to properly show your code in the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by extending WebViewClient and injecting some javascript which will render your web Page

```
public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:your javascript");
}
}
.........
final MyWebClient myWebViewClient = new MyWebClient();
mWebView.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);
```

For hiding elements use `view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';)`

More info [In Android Webview, am I able to modify a webpage's DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219074/in-android-webview-am-i-able-to-modify-a-webpages-dom)

Comment: So for example, if I want to display a div with class "example" I have to write:            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByClassName('example')");
 right?

Comment: @user1960978 You can use the flowing commands  for hiding `document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';` and for showing `document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';`

Comment: where I can find my required javascript ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: @nadeemgc replace `your javascript` in `view.loadUrl("javascript:your javascript");` with javascript which is needed for you.

Comment: @Lemberg I got you. but I am unclear that what will be my javascript. say e.g. I want to hide Gmail button from www.google.com page. What is my javascript code now for this purpose ?

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByClassName('someClass').style.display = 'none'` or `document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';`

Comment: doing this in onpagefinished will initially show the content .. how to avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

The most basic thing to understand here is whether the element we are referring to inside the web html file is a **class** or a **id**. If it is a **id** then `getElementById` works perfectly. If it is a class then `getElementsByClassName` is required.

Following is an example that I am using.

```
myWebView.loadUrl
      ("javascript:(function() { " +
           "document.getElementsByClassName('header_wrapper')[0].style.display='none'; " +
           "document.getElementsByClassName('footer-contact')[0].style.display='none'; "+
           "document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-header')[0].style.display='none'; "+
           "document.getElementsByClassName('footer-social')[0].style.display='none'; "+
           "document.getElementById('footer_bottom').style.display='none'; "+
           "document.getElementById('footer_content').style.display='none'; "+
           "document.getElementById('core_mobile_menu').style.display='none'; "+
           "document.getElementById('catapult-cookie-bar').style.display='none'; "+
       "}
      )()");
```

Comment: this will leave white space after hiding the contents

Comment: When the view loads, the white spaces are there for 1/2 to 1 seconds, but they go away once the full view is loaded. It entirely depends on the device speed.

Comment: no, it stays there in my case, scrollable white space

Comment: [please help me with same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496883/android-webview-display-only-the-content-of-the-website)

Comment: It works fine but when we navigate to some other page and return by pressing the back button it does not work.