# Show only a part of a website in webview

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

can someone give me an example how to view only a part of a website?
I know how to load a website with webview, but as i said i only want to load the table[(Link)](http://roosters.gepro-osi.nl/roosters/rooster.php?klassen%5B%5D=3Ha__W&type=Klasrooster&wijzigingen=1&school=928)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this...

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByClassName('example')"); 
    }

    }
```

have a look at this[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423981/android-webview-display-only-some-part-of-website)

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin this way :

```
view.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                view.loadUrl(
                    "javascript:(function() { " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display='true'; " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('art-bnr')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('container-box')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-sidebar')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                            "})()"
                      ) } }

            view.loadUrl(url)
```