# Load only one div in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to load into the WebView only one `div` with id `results` of all the website.

I have tried adding a JavaScriptInterface like this:

```
        webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void onData(String value) {
              webView.loadData(value, "text/html", null);
        }
```

And inside my WebViewClient:

```
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:android.onData(document.getElementById('results'));");
        }
```

But it simply doesn't works, the whole webpage is loaded instead of the `div` I want.

Comment: "I can't get it to work" -- please explain your exact symptoms.

Comment: have u called webview.javascriptenabled(true)

Comment: yes, I have called it.

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong exactly? Maybe copy-paste the log

Comment: It says I can't run that method outside the webView thread, I have also tried runOnUiThread but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to load the part of the content from the website URL then extend the WebViewClient [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423981/android-webview-display-only-some-part-of-website)

2) Use the JSOUP library to scrap the web page. Get the result from URL parse it take only the `div` with `id` **(result)**

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(LINK_TO_WEBSITE).get();
String content = document.getElementById("pnlResults").outerHtml();
```

and pass those content to the webview in Android.

```
WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: It's not working, I want to get the html code of the div I want to show, not hiding the other elements,

Comment: Okay, I've tried it, but it returns me an empty div without the content:

`<div id="results"></div>`

Comment: Oh I get the problem, this is the url: http://dle.rae.es/?w=hola (the id of the div is "resultados"), but when it finishes loading the url changes and then fills that div. Any idea?

Comment: Can you use  document.getElementsByClass("pnlResults").outerHtml(); ? Note : your sintax not is HTML, is custom object parser!

Comment: I suggested use the JSOUP, because from whole page He want to load specific div code. If you want to syntax fromHtml()  its  not useful in this situation