# Android Webview: Display only the content of the website

Tags: java, android

**I want to hide header and footer of the website but its not working Please Help**

I wanted to know if it was possible to display only certain parts of a website in a WebView.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://myopenhab.org/account");

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var head = document.getElementId('mainHeader').style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");
        }
    }


    @Override
    // This method is used to detect back button
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do scraping via jsoup library. tutorial here: https://www.yudiz.com/data-scraping-in-android-using-jsoupjava-html-parser/

Comment: can u explain more about that url

Comment: i just need the email and password to be displayed

Comment: Yeah then scrapping is best suitable option in this case, else you need to create a new web page that contains only those elements as per your requirement.

Comment: this url is just for information, you can try any tutorial

Comment: okay is there is any easy way

Comment: The easiest and best way is to design that screen by yourself via xml instead of loading it from url.

Comment: i need to login in that with my app

Comment: ok i understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this Javascript Code but its showing website then after its removing

```js
    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var element = document.getElementById('mainHeader');"
                    + "element.parentNode.removeChild(element);" +
                    "var element = document.getElementById('footerRights');"+ "element.parentNode.removeChild(element);" + "})()");

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }


    }
```

---