# Android - after loading URL with webview can i change background color

Tags: javascript, android, security, webview

I have a webview and im loading an external HTML form a site.  I try to change the background color using javascript function:

```
    function changeBGC(color){
document.bgColor = color;
}
```

and that does not work.  but if i load locally then im able to change the background color.  Is there some kind of security inhibiting me from changing a web page i load into the webview externally ?

Comment: You want t change the background color of Webview ? If yes, then you can try using `setBackgroundcolor` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run javascript using the WebViewClient, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219074/in-android-webview-am-i-able-to-modify-a-webpages-dom).

The javascript code that [changes the background color of a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript).

So to put it all together:

When initing WebView:

```
WebView webview = new WebView();
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("stackoverflow.com");
```

Your web view client:

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

    int color;

    public WebClient(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        String command = "javascript:document.body.style.background = " + color + ";";
        view.loadUrl(command);       
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks turns out it was my javascript that was the issue and i changed it as per your provided link.  can you upvote my question i dont know why its voted down.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I upvoted it. I think it was voted down because you haven't tried your javascript code in a browser and posted the question as an Android, while it had a javascript issue.