# Android - Change background color of body after url loads

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I need to change the background color of the body tag in some Html that gets loaded into a webview. I have already tried the answer located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555465/413414). Here is the relevant code I have in `onPageFinished()`:

```
String command = "javascript:document.body.style.background = \"transparent\";";
webView.loadUrl(command);
```

My WebView just ends up ditching the old Html that was originally loaded and displays "transparent" instead of changing the color like I want.

Comment: here is another location about similar problem. u may have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867503/change-background-image-in-body

Answer (score 3):

Changing the javascript to this is what works:

```
String javascript = "javascript:(function() { document.body.style.background='transparent'; })();";
```

if on KitKat+ you can do:

```
String javascript = "(function() { document.body.style.background='transparent'; })();";
webview.evaluateJavascript(javascript, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

[call-a-function-after-complete-page-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936816/call-a-function-after-complete-page-load)

you can do this in javascript code, there is not need to do this in the android java code.