# I have changed the color of accent but it does not apply on webview

Tags: android, webview, colors, styles, themes

I want to change cursor bubble color to orange

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@color/orange</item>
 </style>
```

Why the color of cursor is not getting changed pls help.
Thank you.

Comment: could you please add screenshot and xml code?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null`, the cursor should take the color of `android:textColor`.

Reference from : [Set EditText cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)

Comment: So it's the cursor of what ?

Comment: I think it is of theme

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand which cursor you're talking about. Please clarify this with images or something else.

Comment: the image is not getting uploaded, sorry.

Comment: I have an form on website, when i type on the input there is an cursor , which is green in color, which is by default, this is the cursor which i want change.

Comment: And you are displaying the website page inside a webview ?

Comment: Yes, the website is in webview

Comment: There are some topics on stackoverflow that deal with this kind of problem. Here is an example of changing the background of a webview after loading. You can check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555465/3780625

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the suggestion , i will look into it.

Comment: Np. I can't do much sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.