# Remove banners in the webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, banner, adblock

Is possible remove the banners in a webview? In my webview i display a forum and there is an annoying banner i want to remove.. Is it possible? Is there a way like adBlock or something like that? My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
protected WebView webview;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings websettings = webview.getSettings();
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.proboards.com/");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //super.onSavedInstanceState(outState);

    webview.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(webview.canGoBack() == true)

                webview.goBack();
            else finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide a banner in a specific page, look at the page's source for the banner's id and inject some javascript code (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219074/in-android-webview-am-i-able-to-modify-a-webpages-dom)) in order to set its visibility to hidden.