# WebView: Manipulate DOM after webpage has been loaded

Tags: android, dom, webview

I have a link in my app that points to an external webpage. This webpage is loaded in a webview. So far so good. But the problem with the destination webpage is, that after the page is loaded a div is overlayed over the webpage that the user first has to dismiss.

Is there some possibility to manipulate the DOM after the page was loaded such that I can automatically disable the overlayed dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is very close to your needs:

- [In Android Webview, am I able to modify a webpage's DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219074/in-android-webview-am-i-able-to-modify-a-webpages-dom)

So it is possible using  **loadUrl("javascript:[some javascript here]")** after `onPageFinished()`.