# How can i add Foreign TTF font (Gujarati or Hindi font) to my WebView during loading live URL

Tags: javascript, android, fonts, webview, android-webview

I am developing app for Gujarati Blog. Blog is a mobile friendly design. So I load Blog URL to WebView.

```
webview1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSetting = webview1.getSettings();
        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview1.loadUrl("www.myurl.com");
```

Actually Yet I don't want to go with *Web-service*. So I use WebView for my solution.

It's working fine. But Android Lower version is not supporting Gujarati font. Is there any way to add Gujarati or Hindi font library before loading URL, Or any luck with JavaScript.

*www.myurl.com* is a live URL of my Blog. So I can't add any CSS changes at loading time in my Android app.

Thanks.

Comment: why can't you add CSS to at loading time? You have the webview reference, so you should be able to just [insert a `<link>` using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219074/in-android-webview-am-i-able-to-modify-a-webpages-dom) that points to a webfont?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Can you give me a clue how to implement it ?

Comment: for obsolete Android versions? I'm afraid not- there are no clear cut instructions on making sure someone even *has* support for Gujarati let alone what the system name would be for that.