# How to change image of webpage to local image using Webview in Android?

Tags: android, webview

I want to show local image instead of web page's image using webview in Android.
How can I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about an img element with a local file, if so just use a file:// URL?

Comment: But image is one part of web page and I want to show total part of web page and only change img tag.

Comment: You can load a remote page and then load your own custom javascript to modify the dom of the loaded page. Similar question with answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5010864/1226020